# Handle onBackPressed in Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-navigation

I have implemented navigation Drawer with Navigation Components in Android. I have 5 fragments that I want to go back to my `HomeFragment` when I click on back pressed. For the moment they stay onBackStack and do not go to my desired fragment but go to whatever fragment was first. 
This is my `nav_graph` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            app:startDestination="@id/setupFragment"
            android:id="@+id/treasure_nav"
            android:label="Pick a country">
    <fragment android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
              android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.home.HomeFragment"
              android:label="Home"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_home_fragment_to_namesFragment2"
                app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
                app:destination="@id/namesFragment"/>
        <action android:id="@+id/action_home_fragment_to_quranFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
                app:destination="@id/quranFragment"/>
        <action android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_tasbeehFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
                app:destination="@id/tasbeehFragment"/>
        <action android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_galleryFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
                app:destination="@id/galleryFragment"/>
        <action android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_newsFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
                app:destination="@id/newsFragment"/>
        <action android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_settingsFragment"
                app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
                app:destination="@id/settingsFragment"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/namesFragment"
            android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.names.NamesFragment"
            android:label="Names of Allah"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_names"/>
    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/quranFragment"
            android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.quran.QuranFragment"
            android:label="Quran"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_quran"/>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/tasbeehFragment"
              android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.tasbeeh.TasbeehFragment"
              android:label="Tasbeeh"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tasbeeh"/>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/galleryFragment"
              android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
              android:label="Gallery"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery"/>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/newsFragment"
              android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.news.NewsFragment"
              android:label="News"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news"/>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
              android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.settings.SettingsFragment"
              android:label="Settings"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings"/>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/setupFragment"
              android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.setup.SetupFragment"
              android:label="Pick country"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_setup">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_setupFragment_to_homeFragment3"
                app:destination="@+id/homeFragment"
                app:launchSingleTop="true"
                app:popUpTo="@+id/treasure_nav"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

And this is my `onBackPressed` in my MainActivity (and the only one) :

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
                super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

**Edit**: When i remove the `super.onBackPressed()` and replace it with :
         `findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, false)` I achieve what I want. The only problem is that when I am in the `homeFragment` I want to end the app but I can't.

Comment: couldnt understand the problem from your statment. can you elaborate what actually you want to do on backPress? I have concluded two situations from your statement. One if you have selected any item from nav, then on backpress you want to go to home screen. and again on backpress want to exit the app. Second that on back press you want to change the fragment to home and exit immediate.

Comment: first of all when you are replacing fragments over eachother, you have to use replace fragment instead of add fragment so that they wont stay in backStack

Comment: where do you see the `replace` or the `add` method  o.O

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to go back to HomeFragment wherever you are in the navigation flow. For this case you could try registering OnBackPressedCallback on your Fragments via addOnBackPressedCallback, and call popBackStack to navigate to your HomeFragment. Try adding this to Fragments' onViewCreated that need to go back to HomeFragment on backpress:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        requireActivity().addOnBackPressedCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), () -> {
               navController.popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, false);
            });
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: You did solve my issue although looks like I'm having a lower API, and I am going to update the answer a  little

Answer (score 6):

If you want to close app when press back in **HomeFragment**, it's just specified these attributes of the last action that navigates you to this destination:

1. `app:popUpToInclusive` to `true`
2. `app:popUpTo` to of the last fragment(**SetupFragment**) that navigates you here(**HomeFragment**)

It means change your code like this:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/setupFragment"
          android:name="com.stavro_xhardha.pockettreasure.ui.setup.SetupFragment"
          android:label="Pick country"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_setup">
    <action android:id="@+id/action_setupFragment_to_homeFragment3"
            app:destination="@+id/homeFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/setupFragment"          // this line changes
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />            // and this requires too
</fragment>
```

Comment: No, I am already ok with that. What I need is that when I go from HomeFragment to fragment Gallery, and than to fragment Settings, and than press back, it sends me to the Settings fragment. I dont want this , I want to get back to HomeFragment

Comment: You are in settings and after press back it sends you to settings? wow!

Comment: hello, im really sory about that. it was a mistake: To make the case clear: 
When Navigate from `Home` -> `GalleryFragment` -> `SettingsFragment`. On `SettingsFragment` when I press back, it sends me to the `GalleryFragment`. I want to go to `HomeFragment`.

Comment: this doesn't work also :(

Answer (score 0):

I made this extension function to do just that:

```kotlin
fun Fragment.setupOnBackPressedCallback(block: () -> Unit) {
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner,
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() = block.invoke()
        }
    )
}
```

Inside your fragment, all you have to do is call it passing a lambda:

```kotlin
setupOnBackPressedCallback {
    // Do what you want when you press the back button
}
```